# .net versions supported for Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

Have a function app using .net6.What is the latest .net version Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64 supports?

Comment: This is not a support-site for MS-packages. From the packages site  it's explicitely mentioned, that it support .NEt Framework, not .Net 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64 has
latest version : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64/

But this is for .NET Full Framework.

For .NET Core the latest version is:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.NetCore.retail.amd64

and it supports:  .NET Core 3.0, .NET 5.0, .NET 6.0, .NET 7.0, and .NET 8.0, among other versions.